# How to parse 2 input CSV files using shell script

Tags: shell, csv

How can I read 2 CSV files (data comma seperated) as input using shell script and do operation on that?

File1.csv:

```
ENG_IT,P1234,Ajay,India,ajay.com
ENG_GN,A4324,Raj,England,raj.com
```

File2.csv:

```
P1234,ajay.com
A4324,raj.com
```

Logic: Read 1st column of File1.csv and last column of File2.csv based on common column in both files i.e. (P1234, A4324) and save them as variable like
var1=ENG_IT
var2=ajay.com

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the information already in `file1.csv` (ajay.com and raj.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do with the variables, but you can `join` the two files and then read it in a loop as shown below:

```
join -t, -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -t, -k2 file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) | while IFS=, read -r -a arr
do
    var1=${arr[0]}
    var2=${arr[5]}
    echo "$var1 $var2"
done
```

You can also use `awk` to print out fields:

```
join -t, -1 2 -2 1 <(sort -t, -k2 file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) | awk -F, '{print $1,$5}'
```